# DataSnapshot get one user info every time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I receive FirebaseUser Id & email  how signed in correctly as shown in debug screenshot , but DataSnapshot ds is always loaded with user_01 info , I tried hard to solve this problem and found Similar questions on the site but couldn't  help . so can anyone help to solve this ?

```
public class AddToDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "AddToDatabase";
private ListView userInfolist;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
String userId;
UserInformations uInfo = new UserInformations();
DatabaseReference myRef;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
FirebaseUser user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_database);

    userInfolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userInfolist);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userId = user.getUid();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {                   
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                toastMassege(" You are successfly signed in with " + user.getEmail());
            } else {                 
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                toastMassege(" You are successfly signed out ");
            }
        }
    };        
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {              
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {         
       }
    });
}

Boolean signedstate = true;
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (signedstate) {        
            uInfo.setName(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getName());
            uInfo.setEmail(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getEmail());
            uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getPhone_num());

            arrayList.add(uInfo.getName());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getEmail());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getPhone_num());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            userInfolist.setAdapter(adapter);
            toastMassege("its Done ");
            signedstate = false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void toastMassege(String massege) {
    Toast.makeText(this, massege, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

this is class UserInformations :

```
class UserInformations {

public String email,name,phone_num ;

UserInformations() {
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone_num() {
    return phone_num;
}

public void setPhone_num(String phone_num) {
    this.phone_num = phone_num;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating the adapter inside the for loop. In order to solve your problm, you need to move this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

outside the for loop because you are creating a new instance of `ArrayAdapter` every time you iterate. Please use the following code:

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (signedstate) {        
            uInfo.setName(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getName());
            uInfo.setEmail(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getEmail());
            uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.getValue(UserInformations.class).getPhone_num());

            arrayList.add(uInfo.getName());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getEmail());
            arrayList.add(uInfo.getPhone_num());
            signedstate = false;
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    userInfolist.setAdapter(adapter);
    toastMassege("its Done ");
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but adapter loaded by all  users then I moved signedstate = false; inside for loop then adapter return to the first case and load user_01 info every time .

Comment: I didn't understood you entirely. I moved the `signedstate = false;` inside the loop. See my updaed answer. Does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't , I moved the     signedstate = false;    inside the loop but adapter is still  load user_01 info every time .

Comment: Try to remove the if statement and see if it loads all users. For testing puposes do not use the boolean signedstate. If it works, just change the logic of your condition.

Comment: I removed if statement then adapter load all user info

Comment: That's perfect. Now to get only the users who have the state of signed in, just create a new field for each user named `signedIn` with the default value of false. Every time a users signs in, change the value from false to true. Than just get all the users with the that value set to true. Another approach will be to create another node named singedInUsers in which you can add only the singed in users like this: usersId1: true. The option you used above does not help you.